# Как в apache записать правую часть адресной строки в $_REQUEST

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Нужно, чтобы строка:

```
http://some.com/func/arg1/arg2/arg3
```

Воспринималась как:

```
http://some.com/index.php?request=func/arg1/arg2/arg3
```

то есть, чтобы в `$_REQUEST['request']` было записанно "func/arg1/arg2/arg3"

```
echo $_REQUEST['request']; //выводит func/arg1/arg2/arg3
```

И это воспринималось при **любых** значених (не только func/...), идущих после заданного адреса справа от него и любое количество "слэшей". Что нужно вписать в .htaccess? Или есть иной путь?

Comment: не проще ли обрабатывать сразу `REQUEST_URI`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так вот всё будет передаваться index.php

```
 RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1
```

Comment: мне помог вариант строки: 

     RewriteRule /(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1
    

с этой поправкой принимаю ответ

Comment: (нет времени заняться языком .htaccess, так что до сих пор воспринимаю как черную магию)

Comment: C вашей правкой rewriterule просто никогда не работает. поскольку rule не получает первый слэш. Разбирайтесь, что происходит

Answer (score 2):

Пропишите в `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Или есть иной путь?

Есть. Открою маленький секрет. В НТТР протоколе нет никаких адресных строк, а на сервер и так отправляется только "правая часть" - `/func/arg1/arg2/arg3`. Которая, разумеется, и так **всегда** известна серверу. Без всяких редиректов и самопальных переменных. Лежит в `getenv('REQUEST_URI')`.

Кстати, доброхоты в своих советах забыли про QSA. Так что правильно будет

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: a кокой QSA вы ожидаете из такого url - `http://some.com/func/arg1/arg2/arg3` ? :)